# React hooks - pass JSX Element to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a simple parent/child scenario where I want the child to be responsible for creating some reusable JSX elements that are passed to and rendered by the parent. I cannot find a way that doesn't result in annoying code duplication, exhaustive-deps compiler warnings or an infinite loop. The example below causes an infinite loop because the JSX element `reusableButton` is in the dependency array which apparently changes every time it set.

At the moment i'm probably going to resort to absolute positioning but surely there's a better way to achieve this?

```
function Parent() {
   const [actions, setActions] = React.useState();

   return <>
      <div>{actions}</div>
      ...separation of concerns...
      <Child setActions={setActions} />
   </>
}

function Child(props) {
   const { setActions } = props;

   const reusableButton = <Button>I am reusable</Button>;

   React.useEffect(() => {
      setActions(reusableButton);
   }, [setActions, reusableButton]);

   if (...some condition...) {
      return <div>{reusableButton}</div>;
   } else {
      return <div>don't repeat yourself</div>;
   }
}
```

Comment: `reusableButton` in your example is being recreated on every render, which causes the effect to fire, causing an infinite loop. You could memoize it, move it outside of the function component scope so it's only created once, OR you could rethink your design. What do you need? A component that is reusable, but whose appearance depends on a condition? That's just a normal component!

Comment: Why can't `reusableButton`  just be a separate component? Then you can call it in both `Parent` and `Child`.

Comment: @ericgio This is the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've described and your code example, you should just make a component:

```js
function ReusableButton() {
  return <Button>I am reusable</Button>;
}

function Parent() {
  return (
    <>
      <div><ReusableButton /></div>
      ...separation of concerns...
      <Child />
    </>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  if (...some condition...) {
    return <div><ReusableButton /></div>;
  } else {
    return <div>don't repeat yourself</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: based on what i described this is the right answer. unfortunately in an effort to be concise i left out some detail that means this doesn't actually solve my specific issue. i ended up figuring it out with a set of `useCallback`s and `useMemo`s which seem to be increasingly required in everything i do.

Comment: so it wasn't just a shared element but also shared behavior (callback). so i used `useCallback` to memoize the callback and `useMemo` to memoize the button so that both could be referenced in `useEffect`